# What will happen when finilize method set object's reference to object property

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finalize

Will instances of class `A` be garbage-collected or will they remain in memory forever?

I know that if an object becomes eligible for Garbage Collection and its `finalize()` method has been called and inside this method the object becomes accessible by a live thread of execution, it is not garbage collected.

```
public class A{

  String someString = null;
  private A a=null;
  public String getSomeString() {
    return someString;
  }
  public void setSomeString(String someString) {
    this.someString = someString;
  }
  @Override
  protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    try {
      this.a=this;
      System.out.println("final called");      
    } finally {
      super.finalize();
    }
  }
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  A s1=new A();
  s1=null;
  System.gc();
  System.out.println("gc called");
  ......
}
```

Inspired by [Can we switch off finalizers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950086/can-we-switch-off-finalizers/20950768?noredirect=1#comment31467426_20950768)

Comment: this.a=this wont prevent gc, there are still no reference to this object by something 'life' and therefore it will be gc. If you would reference it from something else (like a live thread) then it would likely to survive.

Comment: @Vladp Make that an answer and you'll get my up-vote...

Comment: @Vladp i think this.a=this assigns reference to it's property?
correct me if i am wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you added

```
this.a=this;
```

is not something that will prevent `A` from being GC, this object is still not being referenced from something valid like a live thread.

Try looking at a more complex structure: `List`

if you point the last node to the first (circular list), and then to set your `Node head = null;` then maybe each node is still being pointed from the other node but the whole List is not being referenced from a live thread and there for will be garbage collected.

Garbage collector is not just checking if the object is being referenced, but **deep** checking if there is a reference from a valid thread.

Bottom line is:

If an object is unreachable from a thread it's garbage collected. In your case A is not reachable any more.

Answer (score 4):

That assignment (in the `finalize()`) method doesn't make the target object  (`this`) strongly reachable, so it won't prevent it from being garbage collected.

On the other hand, if you did this:

```
    otherObject.a = this;
```

and `otherObject` referred to a strongly reachable object, then the assignment *would* make `this` strongly reachable, and it would prevent the object from being collected (while it remained reachable ...).  But next time `this` became unreachable, the `finalize` method would NOT be called.  An object's `finalize` method is only ever called once in the object's lifetime.

---

> i think `this.a=this` assigns reference to it's property? correct me if i am wrong..

You are correct, but it makes no difference.  All you are doing is making `this` point to itself.  That doesn't make it reachable ...

Comment: So there is a way to actually make a memory leak in java? nice.

Comment: @Vladp - Not in the sense that you mean, I think.

Comment: If you call finalize on purpose (and use otherObject.a = this) and then make it unreachable again, the gc wont collect it and it will create a memory leak. wrong?

Comment: @Vladp: you are mixing up things. If you “call finalize on purpose”, it has no effect, the JVM doesn’t care. If *the JVM invoked finalize()*, it won’t do that again on the same object, but that doesn’t prevent *collection* of the object, the object’s memory will just be released without the invocation of `finalize()`.